# Merging two doubly linked lists overwrites one of the two original linked lists

Tags: c++, pointers, merge, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

This is my assignment:

Algorithm Instruction:

1. Create two pointers for the Doubly Linked List one (Head1 and Tail1) and two other pointers for the Doubly Linked List two (Head2 and Tail2)
2. Create another list with two pointers (Head3 and Tail3)
3. Write a function and gets the nodes for the lists from the user
4. Write a function and sort all elements of the two Doubly Linked Lists, in ascending order or descending order
5. Create another function and combine the two sorted Doubly Linked Lists in sorted order
6. Print the combined two Doubly Linked Lists

This is my doubly linked list class:

```
struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node *prev;
    Node *next;
};

class DoublyLinkedList
{
private:
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;

public:
    DoublyLinkedList()
    {
        head = nullptr;
        tail = nullptr;
    }
    void setHead(Node* h)
    {
        head = h;
    }
    void setTail()
    {
        Node* tempNode = head;
        while(tempNode != nullptr)
        {
            if(tempNode->next == nullptr)
            {
                tail = tempNode;
            }
            tempNode = tempNode->next;
        }
    }
    Node* getHead()
    {
        return head;
    }
    Node* getTail()
    {
        return tail;
    }

    void append(int new_data);
    void print() const;
    void backwardDisplay();
    void sort() const;
    Node* merge(Node* h1, Node* h2);
};
```

My main:

```
int main()
{
    DoublyLinkedList dll_1;
    DoublyLinkedList dll_2;
    DoublyLinkedList dll_3;

    int choiceNumber = 0;
    int element = 0;

    while(choiceNumber != 2)
    {
        std::cout << "Please choose:\n";
        std::cout << "1. Add a number to list one.\n";
        std::cout << "2. Move on\n";
        std::cin >> choiceNumber;

        if(choiceNumber == 1)
        {
            std::cout << "Enter a number:\n";
            std::cin >> element;
            dll_1.append(element);
        }
    }

    choiceNumber = 0;

    while(choiceNumber != 2)
    {
        std::cout << "Please choose:\n";
        std::cout << "1. Add a number to list two.\n";
        std::cout << "2. Move on\n";
        std::cin >> choiceNumber;

        if(choiceNumber == 1)
        {
            std::cout << "Enter a number:\n";
            std::cin >> element;
            dll_2.append(element);
        }
    }
    std::cout << "List one unsorted: ";
    dll_1.print();
    std::cout << "List two unsorted: ";
    dll_2.print();

    dll_1.sort();
    dll_2.sort();

    std::cout << "List one sorted: ";
    dll_1.print();
    std::cout << "List two sorted: ";
    dll_2.print();

    dll_3.setHead(dll_3.merge(dll_1.getHead(), dll_2.getHead()));
    dll_3.setTail();
    std::cout << "Combination of list one and two sorted: ";
    dll_3.print();


    dll_1.print();
    dll_2.print();

    dll_3.backwardDisplay();

    return 0;
}
```

And my merge function:

```
Node *DoublyLinkedList::merge(Node* h1, Node* h2)
{
    Node* tempHead1 = h1;
    Node* tempHead2 = h2;
    if (tempHead1 == nullptr)
        return tempHead2;
    if (tempHead2 == nullptr)
        return tempHead1;

    if (tempHead1->data < tempHead2->data)
    {
        tempHead1->next = merge(tempHead1->next, tempHead2);

        return tempHead1;
    }
    else
    {
        tempHead2->next = merge(tempHead1, tempHead2->next);

        return tempHead2;
    }
}
```

When I run my program it works fine, it prints my list1 and list2 in regular and sorted order, and it prints the combined list of list1 and list2, but if I try to print my list1 after the merge function my list1 is also a combination of list1 and list2. I don't understand why but my merge function overwrites one of the original two lists. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If the merge does not create new nodes it will corrupt both original lists.

Comment: How do i make it so it creates new nodes then?

Comment: Probably call your append function

Comment: Why do you need the original list to be preserved? Usually the whole point of merging linked lists is that you do **not** create any new nodes, but reuse the nodes from the original lists. Of course they will become unusable after the merge, that's expected. I recommend  you verify this point with your professor.

Comment: It is strange that `merge` is defined as an instance method on the `DoublyLinkedList` class, but never references the `DoublyLinkedClass` instance members, nor any other `DoublyLinkedClass` instance.